# Fetch data off Couch DB

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I have a CouchDB database with 2 documents.

Doc 1

```
{
  "_id": "001",
  "_rev": "1-xyz",
  "status": "Pending",
}
```

Doc 2 - First Revision

```
{
  "_id": "002"
  "_rev": "1-abc"
  "status": "Pending"
}
```

Doc 2 - Second Revision

```
{
  "_id": "002"
  "_rev": "2-def"
  "status": "Executing"
```

Now, I need to search for documents with "Status" as "Pending". I am using following HTTP cURL Command to do so.

```
curl -X GET 'http://server_name.com:5984/my_tasks/_all_docs?Status=Pending'
```

This cURL Statement returns both the document, but I just want cURL to lookup in the updated revisions not the old ones. In this case I want it to skip First Revision of Document 2. Which cURL Statement should I use for that ?

Comment: You need to create a [view](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/couchdb/7007/views#t=201703132114196654646).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using unsupported Couch HTTP parameters.

For the full list of Query parameters, refer to this [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#get--db-_all_docs).

If you want to query the `_all_docs`endpoint, you can only specify the document id(s) like this : `?key="002"`

If you want to query the document on other fields, you can either:

- Use [map/reduces](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html)
- Use the new [Mango Query Syntax](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/find.html)